# Animated Tint Box

Tags: jquery, animation

How I can do like this ? When I click on the title, I got an animated tint with a text. I can't post images because I am a new user.For example when you click on artwork page : www.alialmasri.com/home.html

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to replicate this...

Comment: what does this have to do with fancybox? .... is not a fancybox issue, is it? unless I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually: Use setTimeout() to increment the appropriate RGB values so that you get the tint you want. You've got to create a valid RGB color string and set the object's CSS color to that value.

This is pretty quick and dirty, but it should give you the basic idea...

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XmuWr/1/

HTML:

```
<span id="tint-me"><b>Tint Me!</b></span>
```

JS:

```
var redColor = 0;

function tint() {
  redColor += 1;
  var colorValue = "#" + redColor.toString(16) + "0000";
  $("#tint-me").css({color: colorValue});
  if (redColor < 255) {
    setTimeout(tint, 5);
  }
}

$("#tint-me").click(function() {
  tint();
});
```